# Ssh to target host via gateway

Tags: networking, ssh

Have a HostA that located in internal subnet which could be seen only from gatway host. Then I issue command like:

```
%ssh -t -o ProxyCommand='ssh GateWayUser@GatWayHost nc HostA 22' HostAUser@HostA ls -la
```

It works fine.

But if I tried it with ~/.ssh/config it doesn't work:

```
% ssh -t HostAUser@HostA ls -la
ssh: connect to host <HostA IP here> port 22: Connection timed out
```

The ~/.ssh/config looks like this:

```
Host TargetHost
HostName It's IP
User It's User

Host GatWayHost 
HostName It's IP
User It's User

ProxyCommand ssh GateWayUser@GatWayHost nc HostA 22
```

Any suggestions how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it the other way round:

```
Host TargetHost
  HostName It's IP
  User It's User
  ProxyCommand ssh GateWayUser@GatWayHost nc HostA 22

Host GatWayHost 
  HostName It's IP
  User It's User
```

You put the proxy command to the match block of respective target host and not vice versa. But you can simplify the command significantly to:

```
ProxyCommand ssh GatWayHost nc %h %p
```

Or just use the internal io forwarding:

```
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p GatWayHost
```

Comment: ProxyCommand ssh GatWayHost nc %h %p - i guess  - typo here, but now it works.